# Java's SecretKeySpec in Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, cryptography, blowfish

I'm trying to port over some `Java` code to `Ruby`. I was given a class that uses several classes in `Java`'s `crypto` package (`javax.crypto.*`) in order to `encrypt` a string using `Blowfish`. There are several parts that I'm stuck on and would love some help.

```
public String encrypt(String var1) throws BlowfishCipher.BCException {
    try {
        byte[] var2 = var1.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] var3 = this.encrypt(var2);
        return bytesToHexString(var3);
    } catch (Exception var4) {
        if(var4 instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException)var4;
        } else if(var4 instanceof BlowfishCipher.BCException) {
            throw (BlowfishCipher.BCException)var4;
        } else {
            throw new BlowfishCipher.BCException(var4);
        }
    }
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] var1) throws BlowfishCipher.BCException {
    try {
        Cipher var2 = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        byte[] var3 = hexStringToBytes(this.sKey);
        SecretKeySpec var4 = new SecretKeySpec(var3, "Blowfish");
        var2.init(1, var4);
        return var2.doFinal(var1);
    } catch (Exception var5) {
        if(var5 instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException)var5;
        } else {
            throw new BlowfishCipher.BCException(var5);
        }
    }
}

private static String bytesToHexString(byte[] var0) {
    StringBuffer var1 = new StringBuffer();

    for(int var2 = 0; var2 < var0.length; ++var2) {
        String var3 = Integer.toHexString(255 & var0[var2]);
        if(var3.length() < 2) {
            var1.append("0");
        }

        var1.append(Integer.toHexString(255 & var0[var2]));
    }

    return var1.toString();
}
```

Again, I can do most of it in `Ruby`, but the thing that I'm missing is the SecretKeySpec. Is there an equivalent in `Ruby`?

My code in Ruby looks something like [this](https://gist.github.com/nono/2995118). The difference is that the `Cipher` I'm newing up is `blowfish` instead of `bf-ecb`

```
OpenSSL::Cipher.new('blowfish').encrypt
```

I also set my own `key_length` because the key that I'm supposed to be using is 14 characters.

Comment: Note that ECB is not secure, and that Blowfish is a cipher with an 8 byte block size, which is also not that secure. If you use encryption for realtime transfer you also need integrity protection / authentication (e.g. using a HMAC). Update you protocol ASAP!

Comment: Any progress after the initial success for the first block, snguyen? It may be another mode of operation, but ECB and CBC are generally the prime suspects.

Comment: $ ruby cipher.rb                                                                             
cipher.rb:5:in `initialize': unsupported cipher algorithm (blowfish-112-ecb) (RuntimeError)                                                    
     
$ ruby cipher.rb                                                                             
cipher.rb:5:in `initialize': unsupported cipher algorithm (blowfish-112-cbc) (RuntimeError)

Comment: Yeah, OK, so maybe you have to construct it differently, providing the blowfish and cbc parameters separately. I saw quite a few ways of constructing ciphers(which has a variable key size).

Comment: I meant blowfish has a variable key size, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java code seems to hex decode the key first. The `SecretKeySpec` is just a wrapper around the (random or pseudo-random) bytes of the key.

So you first need to decode the hexadecimal string and then use that as key:

```ruby
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('blowfish-xxx-ecb')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = [sKey].pack('H*')
return cipher.update(var1) + decipher.final
```

Where xxx is the size *in bits* of the decoded key.

Comment: Note that I'm not a Ruby developer, so please correct syntax errors in above using the edit button.

Comment: So this gets me very close! When I print out the byte array in Java, I get [31, -4, -64, 115, 5, 35, -124]. When I print out the byte array in Ruby, I get [31, 252, 192, 115, 5, 35, 132]. The only difference is, in Java, there are negatives, and in Ruby, there are not.

Comment: Java bytes are always signed (which is actually quite irritating). So bitwise both strings would be identical. I.e. you should be good. Print each byte out after performing `& 0xFF` to see the positive values.

Comment: Ah, crap. The encrypted results are VERY close. Ruby: cf2c2baca6f890630fee34dcdcc0fdaa. Java: cf2c2baca6f890634a3097d20933a84b

Comment: Did you use a specific library / provider for the Blowfish implementation in Java? If yes, which one? Please try `blowfish-xxx-cbc` instead. If that doesn't work, try and set the `cipher.iv` to 8 zero bytes explicitly (16 hex `0`s, you know how to decode now).

Comment: So I'm not sure what the 'xxx' should be. If my key is 14 characters long, is it 'blowfish-14-cbc'? If so, I get `initialize': unsupported cipher algorithm (blowfish-14-cbc) (RuntimeError)

Comment: 14 * 8 = 112 I guess, it's bits, not bytes. Don't think of bytes as characters, even if the language doesn't distinguish between the two. Or 56 if you talk about the key size in *hexadecimal digits*.

Comment: When attempting to encrypt 'mystring', the encrypted string starts to get different at the half way point. I decided to try to encrypt the string 'my', and got the same results between the Java and Ruby version. 'mys' also encrypts to the same string in Ruby and Java. They start diverting when I add 't' ('myst') to the string to encrypt.

Comment: That's very strange. I'll try and think about this, but I'm not sure I understand. Maybe different modes like CFB-24 or something like that, but that would be a very long shot.